# Not able to import custom lookup fields in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lookup-field

I'm not able to import some custom lookup fields in my LWC.

```
import RECTYPE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.RecordTypeId";

import OWNERID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.ownerId";

import RSTORE_ID from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.ShowpadForSF__Showpad_Last_Viewed_Content__c";
```

In above import statement, there is a lookup field

> ShowpadForSF__Showpad_Last_Viewed_Content__c

on Contact and whenever i'm trying to save my code, getting below 'Invalid reference' error.

[image]

This error is appearing only for custom lookup fields as I noticed.
Please help me on this. Totally clueless at the moment. Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: First thing to check - does the user saving the component have at least read access to these fields and a license to access the package they belong to?

Comment: @PhilW It was resolved .. Thank you Phil.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please do take the time to add a self-answer to help others who might face a similar issue in the future.